# save image with text to .png

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

i have a picture box with image, i add text to image.
this works fine.
here is code snippet

```
 Dim MyImg As New Bitmap(PicCropImage.Image)
            Dim MyRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, PicCropImage.Width, PicCropImage.Height)
            PicCropImage.BackColor = Color.White
            Dim g As Graphics = PicCropImage.CreateGraphics

            Using g
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
                g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias
                g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                g.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
                g.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
                g.DrawString(TxtPhotoCaption.Text, FNT, New SolidBrush(CboPhotoCaptionColor.Color), MyRect, format)
                g.DrawImage(MyImg, MyImg.Width, MyImg.Height)
            End Using

            Dim bmpImage As New Bitmap(PicCropImage.Image)

            bmpImage.Save("C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\test8.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            bmpImage.Dispose()
            MyImg.Dispose()
```

[text on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12FqJ.jpg)

problem is when i save the image, the text is not save with it??
[no text on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhyFq.jpg)

can anyone point the error or correct way to add text to image and save the new image with text on it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the `Graphics` object for the `PictureBox` itself, rather than the `Image` in the `PictureBox`. It's like you have a photo behind glass in a frame and you are writing on the glass, then wondering why the picture doesn't have any writing on it. You should be using code like this:

```vb
Using img As New Bitmap(PicCropImage.Image)
    Using g = Graphics.FromImage(img)
        'Use g here.
    End Using

    img.Save("C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\test8.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
End Using
```

NEVER call `CreateGraphics`. If you find yourself doing so, there is a statistically 100% chance that you're doing something wrong.

Note that that is if you want to draw on a copy of the `Image` in the `PictureBox`.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections.  Learning is a never ending process.  I implemented the suggestions, and now it works like i was hoping.  only issue now is getting text centered on image.  Thanks again.  much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't have the full source, so I will make the assumption that PicCropImage is the form control that user inputs the image to be changed. What you do is getting the graphics object of that control instead of the bitmap's. That's why you see the text on the screen, but since it is not part of the bitmap, it's not getting saved.

Try replacing line

```
Dim g As Graphics = PicCropImage.CreateGraphics
```

with this one

```
Dim newGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PicCropImage.Image)
```